# Split Column in two different types (Data flow Task)

Tags: types, ssis, split, multiple-columns

I am currently working on a SSIS Project where i try to get data coming out of SharePoint and Store it into a SQL Server DB.
The following is an example of how the Table will look like in the end:

```
| TableID | Employee | Status* | PlannedAmount*| DateCol |
```

now the data (only speaking of the column that i Need help on now) i get is in the following form:

```
| PlannedValue |     (DT_WSTR datatype)
```

now the above column can either have a Money (money) type value (say 200 or 400, etc.)
or it can be of a textual (varchar(50)) type value("To be authorized" or "not planned yet", etc.).

So what I essentially Need to do is split the Column I get from SharePoint into two new Columns namely: * Status and PlannedAmount.

My question: Has anybody ever done this ?, if so what is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer!
check out [bidn blogs](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/dustinryan/ssis/915/check-isnumeric-with-derived-column-transform-in-ssis-package)